# MY laptop msi gs73vr 7rf fans are not working!

Tags: arch-linux, kernel, kernel-modules, manjaro

I'm wondering why my laptop fans are not working.

MODEL: MSI-GS73vr 7rf stealth pro

I checked thermald

I checked pwmconfig

I checked sensors-lm

I checked arch fan control page

The fan rpm is not showing in the sensors command.
I used the sensors-detect command and other processes.

Still my fans are not working. How can I control them manually?

Answer (score 0):

There's a github project called **isw** and it has a configuration file and a program which writes the fan values to the ec storage. MSI decided to use some proprietary *system* for their fans, but this program does all that for you. I'm also pretty sure it's on the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/isw/).
Make sure to read all the wiki pages on github first though.

Comment: please, use proper syntax